# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_empty' when trying to set new CRS

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I have geodataframe that has two geometry fields.
I'm trying to set new CRS but every time I get the next error message:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_empty'

when I am able to check the original CRS of the layer:

```
print('original crs is:',tost.crs)

>>>original crs is: EPSG:4326
```

but then when I try to set new CRS to the copy:

```
tast = tost.copy()
tast= tast.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})
print('projected the copy df to:',tast.crs)

>>>AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_empty'
```

I don't understand why is this hapenning.
What cause this error?
My goal here is to be able to set the crs

Comment: try `.to_crs(epsg=3857)`

Comment: @sutan I am getting the same error message

Comment: I suspect one of the rows has no geometry. Check if `None` exists in the `geometry` column, like this `>>> True if None in tost.geometry else False`. if this returns True, then there is a `None` in the geometry column, you should drop the row. or filter the none like this `tast = tost[tost.geometry != None]`, then you can do `tast.to_crs(epsg=3857)`

Comment: You can also try column.geometry.is_valid to avoid a few potential problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you don't want to drop any rows?
My solution would be to set the null geometries to be empty geometryCollections.
Then the `to_crs()` method works without throwing any AttributeError.
My code:

```
from shapely.geometry.collection import GeometryCollection

tast['geometry'] = tast.geometry.apply(lambda x: x if x else GeometryCollection())

tast.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})
```